# Making a grid from R into Latex?

Tags: r, matrix, latex, r-grid

I have a grid of values in R (in the form of a matrix.

That is it looks like

```
     0.05  0.06  0.07
0.1   11    12    15
0.11  11    14    15
0.12  13    15    17
...
```

What is the best way to show this in tex?  Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: So you want to generate the LaTeX markup for a table? One such helpful package would be `xtable` package. If you want more specifics, it would be helpful to edit to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with a complete matrix and explicitly give the desired output for your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the xtable function from the xtable library.

EDIT: Sorry for not including sample code:

    `mat <- matrix(c(11, 11, 13, 12, 14, 15, 15, 15, 17), 3, 3)
    library(xtable)
    xtable(mat)`

Comment: Unless you proves some clear sample code, this is really more of a comment/suggestion rather than an answer.